# Stripe.Net Create and Update user

Tags: c#, stripe-payments, stripe.net

Im very new to programing and new to stripe. i am currently trying to create a basic page where i can just create the customers. Im currently using the stripe.net dll and am having a hard time getting this page to work correctly. Here is what i have. I get no errors and no records get created.

Using Stripe;

```
 private StripeCustomer GetCustomer()
    {

        var mycust = new StripeCustomerCreateOptions();
        mycust.Email = "thisisit@overhere.com";
        mycust.Description = "One Time";
        mycust.CardName = "Full Name";
        var customerservice = new StripeCustomerService(System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["StripeApiKey"]);
        return customerservice.Create(mycust);

    }





    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

            StripeCustomer current = GetCustomer();
            var mycharge = new StripeChargeCreateOptions();
            string key = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["StripeApiKey"];
            Response.Redirect("/services/donate/thanks.aspx");


        }

        catch (StripeException ex)
        {
            //lblerror.Text = (ex.Message);

        }


    }
```

Also a little help (as i am lost an nothing i try works) as to how i would go about pulling a list of the current customs i have and display them would be great.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're using this: https://github.com/jaymedavis/stripe.net#list-all-customers

In your GetCustomer method you are creating a customer, instead, you want to do something like the following:

```
private IEnumerable<StripeCustomer> GetCustomers()
{
    var customerservice = new StripeCustomerService(System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["StripeApiKey"]);
    return customerservice.List();
}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        StripeCustomer list = GetCustomers();
        //show this list somewhere

    }
    catch (StripeException ex)
    {
        //lblerror.Text = (ex.Message);

    }
}
```

Makre sure `StripeApiKey` exists in your configuration file.